# Copy range from a sheet and paste into another sheet in different columns

Tags: vba, excel

I've two sheets in my workbook. One is actually a temporary sheet which holds lots of data of employees and there are more than 50 columns. There is another sheet which is limited to 10 columns which is actually filtered list and columns are in order for report. Few columns are formula columns also based on value from another column.

So what I have to do is to copy those columns from Sheet1 `(Temp_Data)` and Paste it into Main sheet with columns been removed and also in a different order.

So what I am doing is, copying it individually and paste it into corresponding columns of the final sheet.

**Like this:**

```
Sheets("Temp_Data").Range(cells(2,1),cells(lastrow,1)).copy
Sheets("Final_Invoice").Range("G2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


Sheets("Temp_Data").Range(cells(2,7),cells(lastrow,7)).copy
Sheets("Final_Invoice").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

So this process repeats for all columns required from `Temp_Data` into `Final_Invoice`.

But I really believe there should be some easiest way to replace this like mapping between columns.

Any suggestions deeply thankful

Comment: `replace this like mapping between columns` .. um, like *linked* cells?

Answer (score 0):

At least you can have it in a shorter version. When I am doing this kind of copy and paste I have basically an own match function like this (because you sometimes get unforseen errors with Application.Match):

```
Function ownMatch(s As String, rng As Range) As Long
  ownMatch = 0
  On Error Resume Next ' resume if error occurs after this
  ownMatch = Application.Match(s, rng, 0) ' get cell with value s in it
  On Error GoTo 0 ' turn on errors again
End Function
```

Then I simply use that function in a loop. So when you have 10 columns it could look like this:

```
Sub copyAndSortCols()
Dim i As Long, lColToCopy As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim vColumnsToCopy
Dim wsTemp As Worksheet, wsFinInv As Worksheet
  [... other code ...]
  Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempData")
  Set wsFinInv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final_Invoice")
  vColumnsToCopy = Array("Column1", "Column2", "Column3") ' fill this with your column names that you want to copy
  For i = 0 To UBound(vColumnsToCopy)
    lColToCopy = ownMatch(CStr(vColumnsToCopy(i)), wsTemp.Rows(1)) ' find column in row 1 of TempData
    If lColToCopy > 0 Then ' if there is a match
      wsTemp.Range(wsTemp.Cells(1, lColToCopy), wsTemp.Cells(lastrow, lColToCopy)).Copy _
        Destination:=wsFinInv.Cells(1, i + 1)
    End If
  Next i
  [... other code ...]
End Sub
```

Make sure that you fill the array in the same order the columns should be pasted into the other sheet. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the names of the columns you want to paste into are contained in row 1 of the destination sheet and exactly match the names of the columns in the sources sheet, also in row 1. In that case you can simply loop through all the headings in the source sheet and check if they exist in the destination sheet. If a match is found copy the column.

Here is a basic working example

```
Sub copyColumns()

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Define sheet with source columns
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Destination sheet, this contains the columns headings

    For intCol1 = 1 To wsSource.UsedRange.Columns.Count

        For intCol2 = 1 To wsDest.UsedRange.Columns.Count

            If LCase(wsSource.Cells(1, intCol1)) = LCase(wsDest.Cells(1, intCol2)) Then
                wsSource.Columns(intCol1).Copy
                wsDest.Cells(1, intCol2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


            End If
        Next intCol2


    Next intCol1

End Sub
```

If you're trying to do something else, please leave a comment

Comment: Unfortunately the headers are different

Comment: In that case, the solution you posted seems pretty efficient

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ashleedawg for mapping hint. Im sharing a solution I tried which does the purpose. But its not a clean solution, but for those having similar scenario can use this.

First I created a mapping array which looks like this

```
dim mapper() as string
mapper=split("A-D,B-H,E-A,G-E",",")
```

Here we are mapping the column from the source sheet into dest sheet. For example in A-D means Temp table A column maps to D column in dest sheet

```
dim s as variant
for each s in mapper
    Dim map() As String
    map = Split(s, "-")
        With Sheets("Invoice")
            myRange.Range(Cells(1, CInt(map(0))), Cells(myRange.Rows.count, CInt(map(0)))).Copy
            .Range(map(1) & "2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End With
next
```

Loop is actually iterating through the array created by splitting using - (hyphen) which gives all columns mapping. Again inside of the loop we are splitting into different parts for source and destination.